# quotations marks encoding in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I downloaded a webpage and it contains paragraph having this type of quotations marks

“I simple extracted this line from html page”

but when I write then to file then this “ character is not properly shown.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
Stream strm = wc.OpenRead("http://images.thenews.com.pk/21-08-2013/ethenews/t-24895.htm");
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D://testsharp.txt");
String line;
Console.WriteLine(sr.CurrentEncoding);

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    sw.WriteLine(line);
}
sw.Close();
strm.Close();
```

Comment: "but when I write then to file then this “ character is not properly shown." - so what *is* shown, and how are you looking? (in a text editor? in the debugger?)

Comment: Also: do you know what *encoding* the source is in? Try specifying that explicitly, so that it doesn't have to make any assumptions; the `“` character is not ASCII, so the encoding is very important

Comment: I am looking in text editor sublime text and � this character is shown.

Comment: The webpage is likely in UTF-8 and your text editor is likely displaying it in ASCII. What text editor are you using?

Comment: I try using iso-8859-1 encoding but not worked

Comment: @musefan I disagree; it is not implicit that the text editor is the issue.

Comment: Well as you guys think you can solve it with code then I have retracted my vote. You guys can look after OP now, I'm off for beer

Comment: View the source of the html page, normally in the first couple lines it will say what encoding is used

Comment: @user2339694 AFAIK, iso-8859-1 doesn't event contain that character

Comment: Verified: iso-8859-1 ***does not contain*** `“`. The html on that page claims to be iso-8859-1, but then contains byte sequences that are *not valid* in that character set. I would be inclined to assume it is actually UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to write the file to disk, then: use the `Stream` API *directly*, or (even easier) just use:

```
wc.DownloadFile("http://images.thenews.com.pk/21-08-2013/ethenews/t-24895.htm",
    @"D:\testsharp.txt");
```

If you don't treat it as binary, then you need to worry about *encodings* - and it isn't enough just to look at `sr.CurrentEncoding`, because we can't be sure that it *detected it* correctly. It *could* be that the encoding was reported in the HTTP headers, which would be nice. It could *also* be that the encoding is specified in a BOM at the start of the payload. However, in the case of HTML the encoding could also be specified inside the HTML. In all three cases, treating the file as binary will improve things (for the BOM and inside-the-html cases, it will fix it entirely).

Comment: I want to display that text in richTextBox form.

Comment: Then use `DownloadString`, but note that you'll still hit problems if your encoding is wrong.